# Picture and bullet points next to eachother within columns as divs

Tags: html, css

I have been browsing and searching around for sometime now to find a working example of a picture in one column and text with bullet points in the other.
This is my result so far.

[image]

As you can see the text doesn't start at the top as I want it to.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;display:table">
<div style="display:table-cell;background:red">
    <img src="http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/bpictures/4795.jpg" />
</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;width:100%;background:grey;">
    <p>
        Here is some text about how awesome Spongebob squarepants is!
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>Home
            <ul>
                <li>Dashboard</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Views
            <ul>
                <li>Tickets</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Customers
            <ul>
                <li>List of Customers</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Conditional
            <ul>
                <li>Admin extension</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Link to example in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xetLv6hy/1/)

Comment: Doesn't work, or I am simply adding it at the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xetLv6hy/2/)

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;display:inline-flex">
```

just change the display css to inline-flex

Answer (score 0):

try this.. I think this is what you're looking for.

```
<div style="float:left; background:red">
    <img src="http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/bpictures/4795.jpg" />
</div>
<div style="background:grey; float:left;">
<p>
    Here is some text about how awesome Spongebob squarepants is!
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Home
        <ul>
            <li>Dashboard</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Views
        <ul>
            <li>Tickets</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Customers
        <ul>
            <li>List of Customers</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Conditional
        <ul>
            <li>Admin extension</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @RickyAlexandersson there I've updated my answer... if this helps you don't forget to check and upvote my answer.. ty =)

Answer (score 0):

How about you actually use a table if you want the get that effect.

Try this html in the snippet:

```html
<table >
    <tr>
    <td style="display:table-cell;background:red">
        <img src="http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/bpictures/4795.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td style="display:table-cell;width:100%;background:grey;">
        <p>
            Here is some text about how awesome Spongebob squarepants is!
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>Home
                <ul>
                    <li>Dashboard</li>
                </ul>
           </li>
           <li>Views
                <ul>
                    <li>Tickets</li>
                </ul>
           </li>
           <li>Customers
                <ul>
                    <li>List of Customers</li>
                </ul>
           </li>
           <li>Conditional
                <ul>
                    <li>Admin extension</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You gonna have to change your `divs` into `table` and `td` respectively and add your `td` items (img and text containers) into `tr`.

If you have some constraints about this solution let me know.

ADVICE:

don't use inline styles, your markup gets really messy and it's difficult to make any changes later on.

Comment: I'll keep your comment about the inline styles in mind.
For my current issue the inline-flex serves as a better solution.
Regards
Ricky